# Is there any convention/best practice for test directory location in a React project?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am starting to learn React and I am using Jest to create to unit tests. As a Java backend developer I am used to comply with a specific project structure, e.g.

```
module/
  src/
    main/
      java/
    test/
      java/
```

therefore I was wondering if there are any best practices that I should be aware of when it comes to project structure of a React project, especially in terms of test file location.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 4):

I usually create a directory for each component, so test file is in same directory with component.

Comment: I do the same as @no1lov3sme and keep any component specific documentation; css modules and story.js files in there too.